# PHP - proxy checker multi-threaded

Tags: php, multithreading, proxy

I already made my personal single thread proxy checker using php,but I couldnt make it multi-thread,some days ago,I found one checker using multi-thread on github,can someone help to change it to save the good proxies into a file (ip:port format)?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samuel-allan/FastProxyChecker/master/checker.php

What i have tried:

```
original line 91:
echo json_encode($arr);

changed to:

$json = json_decode($arr);
$good_proxie = $json['arr']['result']['proxy']['ip'];
echo "$good_proxie";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not checked it, but think it'll work ^_^

```
function CheckMultiProxy($proxies, $timeout, $proxy_type)
{
    $data = array();
    foreach($proxies as $proxy)
    {
        $parts = explode(':', trim($proxy));
        $url = strtok(curPageURL(),'?');
        $data[] = $url . '?ip=' . $parts[0] . "&port=" . $parts[1] . "&timeout=" . $timeout . "&proxy_type=" . $proxy_type;
    }
    $results = multiRequest($data);
    $holder = array();
    foreach($results as $result)
    {

        $holder[] = json_decode($result, true)["result"];
    }
    $arr = array("results" => $holder);

    foreach ($arr['results'] as $proxy) {
        if ($proxy['success']) {
           file_put_contents('YOUR_FILE_HERE', $proxy['proxy']['ip'].':'.$proxy['proxy']['port'].' '.$proxy['proxy']['type'].PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: Hello brother , I tried your code but it gives me error "{"results":[null,null,null,null..............."  , and no file is created (I set the file name to good-proxies.txt)

Comment: can you please give a var_dump of one $proxy in the foreach - so I'll improve it: just put var_dump($proxy) before the file_put_contents - and give the result to me

Comment: the "var_dump($proxy)" returns: "NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL.........)  and the original script shows: "{"results":[{"success":true,"proxy":{"ip":"103.21.160.156","port":"9999","speed":3833,"type":"http(s)"}},{"success":true,""

Comment: Nice brother,now it is checking and saving to file , but the last lines are bugged , result: "`103.250.166.4:6667 http(s)
103.241.227.98:6667 http(s)
103.240.161.101:6667 http(s)
103.216.82.37:6667 http(s)
103.216.82.52:6667 http(s)
103.216.82.22:6667 http(s)
: 
: 
: 
: 
: 
: `" I think that this ":" is because of the bad proxies,what can I do to remove them?

Comment: I've added a check - if ($proxy['proxy']['success']) { :) try again

Comment: I just have to fix a little error in your last script,i changed this part:                                                              
         `foreach ($arr['results'] as $proxy) {
         ***if ($proxy['success']) {***
            file_put_contents('working.txt', 
   $proxy['proxy']['ip'].':'.$proxy['proxy']['port'].PHP_EOL, 
   FILE_APPEND);
         }
     }`                                          Now the script is working 100% , thank you very much dude.

Comment: sorry mate - I had no data to test it ^_^ hope it'll help you:)